# bind existing object to checkbox to push and splice new values

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

This application is used to add parameters to an exercise to tailor it for a customer/client.

The exercise object looks like this (a number of other values have been removed for simplicity):

```
{
  "exerciseName": "Squat",
  "Params": [{
      "param": "Sets",
       "childParam" : ""
       }, {
       "param": "Reps",
       "childParam" : ""
   }]
}
```

I would like to provide the user a number of checkboxes to quickly add/remove Params to/from this exercise.

The options array currently looks like this:

```
$scope.availibleParams = [{
    "param": "Reps",
    "childParam": ""
}, {
    "param": "Tempo",
    "childParam": ""
}, {
    "param": "Sets",
    "childParam": ""
}, {
    "param": "Weight",
    "childParam": ""
}, {
    "param": "Rest",
    "childParam": ""
}];
```

So in this particular example, when the exercise loads the checkboxes for the `param` "Reps" and "Sets" would be already checked as they are present in the active Exercise.

Upon checking new params they should be pushed into the activeExercise array, and vice versa they should be removed if unchecked.

Further to this requirement I also need to be able to add Custom Parameters. These are once that the user can add if the option is present in the above list. Once they have added their custom parameter it should show on both the exercise and checkbox list.

I have managed to experiment with finding to the `activeExercise.Params` array and managed to `ng-repeat` the options, however binding to this and running the required add / remove function on checking and unchecking is proving too difficult for my IQ!

I have created a [Pen](https://codepen.io/Taylorsuk/pen/MmwWoV?editors=1010) on CodePen to show where I have managed to get to.

Additionally, I have no idea what to title this post, feel free to correct me.

Comment: The question is missing the HTML and the controller code. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce **it in the question itself.** Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You can use the Pen provided in the question.

Comment: The controller and HTML is in the Pen... I was aiming to be concise.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but maybe you need this?

I have one array with parameters, and have property **isActive**

```
$scope.availibleParams = [{
    "param": "Reps",
    "isActive": true,
    "childParam": ""
}, ...
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qmdBeE?editors=1010

More complex case:

We still have **isActive** property, but we check onchange event for what is actual happened, so

1) We initialize our active exercises, and set available params to Active state if they are presented in **$scope.activeExercise**. Take a look at that function:

```
scope.initActiveExercices()
```

2) We sync both custom and available exercises in **$scope.updateActiveExercices()**.

At first we clear **$scope.activeExercise** array

And then we iterating over available and custom params arrays, and look at isActive property, if its true we push to **$scope.activeExercise** array

That is it.

Here is new copeden [example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qmdBeE?editors=1010)

Comment: Thanks, that helps, but I am would have to run a loop to add these `isActive` values on a function each time as they are not present in the original data, which is impossible to change throughout the whole DB.

Comment: you can create addition property like isCutom: true for all custom created parameters

Comment: Simple for the ones that are being created, however there are 4000 existing  exercises without ant `isActive` properties, therefore it needs to be added on initialisation of the page or something.

Comment: This is really close... When I save the exercise I think I am going to have to strip out all of the `isActive` but I think that this is going to be pretty simple to achieve. 
Thanks very much, I hope to do some testing in the app and then mark this as correct.